# Google analytics - 2 views or properties for subdomain

Tags: google-analytics

I'm launching separate e-commerce stores in both the US and the UK. The sites will be almost identical, selling almost identical products.

The UK will be on a uk. subdomain of the main URL.

Anyone visiting the main URL from the UK will be redirected to UK site based on their IP address.  Some marketing links and any visual marketing will always have to go to the main URL, so there will be some redirects.

In the long run (1-2 years) I hope to be able to merge the sites.

Question: should this be two views or two properties?  I've had some feedback saying the users act very differently in the two countries so different properties should be used.

Will the redirects be easier to monitor in either set up?  Will I be better able to see the true source of redirects to the UK by using views instead?

I'm very new to this so please feel free spell out anything obvious!

Thanks for any thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely set up two properties. Even though the sites are very similar in content, they are still different sites. They serve two different regions, with different internet laws, different currencies, etc. Also, since many sites tend to place different content on subdomains than top level domains, search engines tend to treat each subdomain as a separate website.

As they are separate sites, treating them as such in Analytics will make your life easier when you want to troubleshoot issues, or experience a difference in rankings. If a property is a web entity and a view is a configuration of that entity, your separate entities deserve their own properties, each with its own view(s).